# Magento upgrade 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2 conflicts

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, conflict

I am try to upgrade my magento from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.4 but gives following errors

```
    Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
    Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
    Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.1
    and so on....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you missed the package Info file which is created by Magento by default when it is installed for the first time.

Go to `pkginfo` and delete the file `Mage_All_Latest.txt`.

Then you're all set.

**Hope this works for you**

Answer (score 1):

Look at the top of these errors, there must be an error showing that the `magento_all_lates.txt` can't be deleted from `/pkginfo`. Try to delete that file manually. Then try again.

***Hope this will solve your problem***